# Flexbox is using original SVG width instead of scaled width

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I am trying to make a section which has 2 flex `div` boxes where:

- Left one: Has the auto width of a `img`.
- Right one: Has the left width.

I have almost everything working, but I am stuck with this:

[image]

It seems to set the original width of the SVG file, not the "scaled" one. The SVG image is contained in an `img` tag and scaled with `height: 100%;` and `width: auto;`.

I have been searching for multiple solutions in internet but none of them worked.

Is there any way to solve it? (without JavaScript if possible)

---

*index.htm*

```
<div id="SideMessage">
    <div class="Decoration">
        <img src="./image.svg" alt="ERROR">
    </div>
    <div class="Message">
        <span>SAMPLE TEXT</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

*style.css*

```
div#SideMessage {
    /**/background: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    height: 64px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
        div#SideMessage > div.Decoration {
            /**/border: 1px dashed green;
            flex-basis: auto;
            flex-grow: 0;
            flex-shrink: 0;
        }
        div#SideMessage > div.Message {
            /**/border: 1px dashed red;
            flex-basis: auto;
            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-shrink: 1;
        }
                div#SideMessage > div.Decoration > img {
                    height: 100%;
                    width: auto;
                }
                div#SideMessage > div.Message > span {
                    font-size: 20px;
                    letter-spacing: 2px;
                }
```

*image.svg*

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18.475px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 18.475 32">
    <polygon fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" points="0,0 18.475,0 0,32"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Seems to already be working as desired from the code you have above https://jsfiddle.net/3ys4n9bp/ the svg dimensions are `34.8834px` x `62px`?

Comment: @Zze A part of the image is cut off (tried with both Firefox and Chrome), what I want to see is the whole image inside its container.

Comment: So your question is actually: "Flexbox is using original svg width instead of scales width"'?

Comment: @Zze Yes, much better! I edited the title with your suggestion.

Comment: If you remove `height:100%` from the svg it will scale and be contained. If you still need it to take the whole height, you'll need to give the decoration more width (at 64px high, you'll need 36.95px) to maintain the svg aspect ratio.

Comment: @AlexGrant Yes, I know. But I need CSS to calculate it automatically by itself, because the `height` of the whole block will change (and, of course, I don't want to calculate every situation, that won't be efficient).

Comment: It would be helpful to state all of the constraints of the problem (what parts are changing).

Comment: @AlexGrant Sorry, I don't understand, what do you need?

Answer (score 0):

2 years later but unwrapping the `<img>` from `<div class="Decoration">` should fix it. And add `box-sizing: border-box;` to prevent overflow from its border/padding.